# SonarQube Update Database for Version 7 Fails

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We are running setup to update our SonarQube to version 7.0 - we get a database failure (see stack trace below).

Any idea how we can get past this?

```
2018.02.07 07:16:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] Starting DB Migration and container restart
2018.02.07 07:16:47 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] Executing DB migrations...
2018.02.07 07:16:47 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1907 'Populate table live_measures'...
2018.02.07 07:16:48 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] #1907 'Populate table live_measures': failure | time=788ms
2018.02.07 07:16:48 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: failure | time=790ms
2018.02.07 07:16:48 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration failed | time=902ms
2018.02.07 07:16:48 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.DatabaseMigrationImpl] DB migration ended with an exception
org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepExecutionException: Execution of migration step #1907 'Populate table live_measures' failed
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:79)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:67)
       at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
       at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:590)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:52)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.engine.MigrationEngineImpl.execute(MigrationEngineImpl.java:50)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doUpgradeDb(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:105)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.DatabaseMigrationImpl.doDatabaseMigration(DatabaseMigrationImpl.java:80)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during processing of row: [uuid=eea5cd4b-3c1c-4001-bf83-85c1062a1b7c,project_uuid=3dabb938-1a4a-4c82-b0a7-0b20cc419be9,metric_id=10019,value=1,text_value=null,variation_value_1=0,measure_data=null]
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.SelectImpl.newExceptionWithRowDetails(SelectImpl.java:89)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:81)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MassUpdate.execute(MassUpdate.java:91)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.version.v70.PopulateLiveMeasures.execute(PopulateLiveMeasures.java:57)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.DataChange.execute(DataChange.java:44)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:75)
       ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SONARQUBE_IDM.LIVE_MEASURES_COMPONENT) violated
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10032)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeLargeBatch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1364)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9839)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:234)
       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.UpsertImpl.addBatch(UpsertImpl.java:42)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MassUpdate.callSingleHandler(MassUpdate.java:118)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MassUpdate.lambda$execute$0(MassUpdate.java:91)
       at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:78)
       ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: An expected measure can't be migrated. Do/did you have custom plugins?

Comment: Could you please provide the results of the following SQL request?

SELECT p.uuid, p.project_uuid, pm.metric_id, pm.value, pm.text_value, pm.variation_value_1, pm.measure_data 
FROM project_measures pm 
INNER JOIN projects p on p.uuid = pm.component_uuid
INNER JOIN snapshots s on s.uuid = pm.analysis_uuid
WHERE s.islast = 1 and pm.person_id is null 
and pm.component_uuid = 'eea5cd4b-3c1c-4001-bf83-85c1062a1b7c'
and pm.metric_id = 10019

Answer (score 5):

we had the same issue.

> Execution of migration step #1907 'Populate table live_measures'
>   failed;[...]ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "live_measures_component

I checked the entries in our DB that are causing the issue with this query (we use PostgreSQL, so you have to check if the query syntax is still valid for Oracle):

```
SELECT p.uuid, pm.metric_id, COUNT(1) FROM project_measures pm INNER JOIN projects p on p.uuid = pm.component_uuid INNER JOIN snapshots s on s.uuid = pm.analysis_uuid WHERE s.islast = TRUE and pm.person_id is null GROUP BY p.uuid, pm.metric_id HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

There were > 3.500 (!) entries with the same uuid and metric_id, so no chance to manually adjust some table entries.

As we did not have enough time to analyze this further and we wanted to get past this we decided to delete and recreate the index "live_measures_component" without the UNIQUE key on the table live_measures.

The following statements should work for you as well: (with large databases the duration of these statements should be taken into consideration...)

```
DROP INDEX "live_measures_component";
CREATE INDEX live_measures_component ON live_measures (component_uuid,metric_id);
```

This workaround allowed us to finish the database migration. I don't know if the workaround has some side-effects (maybe somebody from sonarqube can tell) - but with having > 3.500 "problematic" entries in the DB it was our only possiblity at the moment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you - dropping and recreating the index fixed the problem and we were able to complete the update

Comment: I also hope that someone from SonarQube reads this and explains the side effects. The above solution worked for me in MySQL. I only had 88 entries.

Answer (score 1):

(no rep, can't comment): the previous answer by guenther-s initially worked, but caused our analysis to later fail with sonar 9.7:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

when inserting into the live_measures table. we fixed ours by dropping the index, removing the duplicates and re-adding a unique index after that:

```
DROP INDEX "live_measures_component";
DELETE FROM
    live_measures a
        USING live_measures b
WHERE
    a.updated_at < b.updated_at
    AND (a.component_uuid = b.component_uuid AND a.metric_uuid = b.metric_uuid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX live_measures_component ON live_measures (component_uuid,metric_uuid);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had the exact same problem with a SonarQube DB migration.